# Addition in differential equations

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I am learning simple differential equations, and I know that the way they are solved is basically some magic with $dy$ and $dx$ behaving like normal fractions but then suddenly being integrated and I find this whole thing a bit weird as I can't explain to myself how come this works.
However, while trying to solve a simple equation $y' = y + a$, I came up with this:
$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = y + a \\
\frac{dy}{y+a} = dx \\
\int \frac{1}{y+a} dy = \int 1 dx \\
\text{substitute u = y + a} \\
\text{therefore dy = d(u - a) = du - da} \\
\int \frac{1}{u} du - da = \int 1 dx \\
\int \frac{1}{u} du - \int 1 da = \int 1 dx \\
\ln u - a = x \\
\ln (y+a) = x + a \\
y = e^{x+a} - a 
$$
I checked the solution and it seems correct but the whole substitution thing seems a bit... sketchy to me. Therefore I ask, is this a valid way of solving differential equations?

Note: I omitted the constants for simplification

Comment: $\frac{1}{u}(du-da)=\frac{1}{u}du-\frac{1}{u}da$

Answer (score 1):

You mention that you have omitted the constants for simplification, however it appears that $a$ is a constant in this equation, as I can't decipher what the independent variable of $a$ is. Assuming that $a$ is constant, a solution to this ODE is 
$$y(x)=ce^x-a$$
for $c$ constant.

The part where you're going awry is where you $u$-substitute.

Your choice of $u$ is good, however it's not valid to say $dy = d(u-a)$ because $a$ is constant. Your $du$ for this substitution will just be  $dy$ since $u$ is a function of $y$. That is,
$$u(y)=y+a\\ \frac{du}{dy}=1\\du=dy$$

Comment: Yes, $a$ is just an arbitary number. Also, I found that another solution to this particular equation is $y = 1 - a$. Any way to get to this solution from the equation?

Comment: $y=1-a$ is not a solution to the original ODE. You can see this if you try substituting it into the original equation, $\frac{dy}{dx}=y(x)+a$. If, $y=1-a$, then $\frac{dy}{dx}=0$. Thus you get $0=(1-a)+a=1$ and $0=1$ is a contradiction.